# How to implement GitHub provider auth using firebase UI in Android

Tags: android, github, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I create an android app that let users to signin using google, Facebook, LinkedIn and twitter account using [Firebase UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android). I want to integrate GitHub button so that users can signin using their GitHub account. I already read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/github-auth) related to GitHub auth but it is not clear. I already create my app using [this link](https://github.com/settings/developers) and I put Client ID and Client Secret in firebase console. How can I add GitHub button in my xml layout? When users hit the button which Intent to call and how to handle the response?

Somebody to help on this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it correctly is actually really hard, but we have plans to add support for the GitHub provider in FirebaseUI 3.4. Feel free to check out my PR and fork it if needed: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/pull/1199.

Comment: Great. Thank a lot for your answer. I am waiting for new release. Have a good day.